# exporting name of last but one directory

Tags: linux, bash, pwd

As explained in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1371261/get-current-directory-name-without-full-path-in-bash-script/1371283?noredirect=1#comment43467575_1371283), we can get name of current working directory.
But how to get last but one directory name?

Scenario:

```
# working directory /etc/usr/abc/xyz.txt 
printf '%s\n' "${PWD##*/}" #prints abc
#i want to print usr
printf '%s\n' "%{PWD##*/-1}" #prints me whole path
```

Suggest me how to do this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @EtanReisner try `echo ${PWD##*/}`

Comment: Bah, sorry, artifact of my fake test and a working directory of a filename there.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The classic way would be:

```
echo $(basename $(dirname "$PWD"))
```

The `dirname` removes the last component of the path; the `basename` returns the last component of what's left.  This has the additional merit of working near the root directory, where variable editing with `${PWD##…}` etc does not necessarily work.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you don't just want to run `basename "$(dirname "$PWD")"` for some reason and you really want to use expansion for this (note the caveats [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22402242/258523)) you would want to use.

```
# Strip the current directory component off.
tmppwd=${PWD%/*}
# Strip all leading directory components off.
echo "${tmppwd##*/}"
```

But the array expansion trick mentioned in one of the linked comments is clever (though tricky because of other expansion properties like globbing, etc.).