# What does 'cd ${0%/*}' mean in bash?

Tags: bash

I encountered a [git commit](https://github.com/dominictarr/JSON.sh/commit/e028db56fc3bf1f7e28b6b58f8a9d19edcfe57cc?diff=split) which cleans up some `readlink` and `dirname` command with this magic variable substitution `cd ${0%/*}`.

How does bash interpret it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22401091/bash-variable-substitution-vs-dirname-and-basename

Comment: http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion

Comment: Tangentially, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4685615/search-engine-for-special-characters wasn't helpful here.  I'm sure there are duplicates on StackOverflow but I can't find them.

Comment: (But doing `man bash` and searching for just a percent sign will quickly find the relevant documentation.)

Answer (score 17):

The `%` here is called pattern-matching operator.

A quote from *Learning the Bash Shell* book:

The classic use for pattern-matching operators is in stripping off components of pathnames, such as directory prefixes and filename suffixes. With that in mind, here is an example that shows how all of the operators work. Assume that the variable `path` has the value `/home/cam/book/long.file.name` ; then:

```
Expression         Result                                Comments
${path##/*/}                      long.file.name   ## takes out longest matched substring from the front
${path#/*/}              cam/book/long.file.name   # takes out shortest matched substring from the front
$path              /home/cam/book/long.file.name   
${path%.*}         /home/cam/book/long.file        % takes out shortest matched substring from the rear
${path%%.*}        /home/cam/book/long             %% takes out longest matched substring from the rear
```

These can be hard to remember, so here's a handy mnemonic device:

- `#` matches the front because number signs precede numbers;
- `%` matches the rear because percent signs follow numbers.

In your specific case, `0` is the counterpart of the `path` in my example, so you should know it.

If `$0` is `/home/chj/myfile.txt` , `cd ${0%/*}` will expand to be `cd /home/chj`, i.e. stripping of the "file" part.

I understand your urge to ask this question, because it is too hard to search for the answer without several hours digging into a Bash book.

Answer (score 10):

The command `cd ${0%/*}` changes directory to the directory containing the script, assuming that `$0` is set to the fully-qualified path of the script.