# sed or some other command line tool to remove last occuring /

Tags: bash, shell, sed, terminal, text-manipulation

I want to create a function in my bashrc, cwhich , which will store the result of which $1 in a path var, then cd to it. But this will start a piece of software, such as cwhich python, cwhich blender, etc. I want to cut off the text after the last occurring / and then cd to the valid directory. Its only a minor inconvenience but by finding or seeking solutions to them I hope to become more pragmatic, efficient and knowledgeable. Help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The external tool you want to use for this is `dirname`.

So your function would look like this:

```
cwhich() {
    local bin=$(which "$1")
    local bindir=$(dirname -- "$bin")

    cd -- "$bindir"
}
```

That being said that's two external tools for this which is two more than you really need here.

You should use either `type -p` or `command -v` instead of `which`. They are both standardized (`which` is not) and are both shell built-ins (`which` is not) so they are more portable, guaranteed to be there, and going to be faster as they don't spawn an external process. (We can't avoid the sub-shell for those though.)

That makes the function:

```
cwhich() {
    local bin=$(command -v -- "$1")
    local bindir=$(dirname -- "$bin")

    cd -- "$bindir"
}
```

That still leaves `dirname` though and we don't need to use that for this we can use [Shell Parameter Expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) instead and save the external process (and the sub-shell this time):

```
cwhich() {
    local bin=$(command -v -- "$1")
    local bindir=${bin%/*}

    cd -- "$bindir"
}
```

It should be noted that `dirname` and `${var%/*}` are not strictly identical. There are some corner cases where they differ but for this usage I don't believe any of those corner cases matter. (See [this fantastic answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22402242/258523) for more discussion about this difference.)

You may notice that there isn't any error checking in this function. We should probably add that now.

```
cwhich() {
    local bin=$(command -v -- "$1")
    local bindir=${bin%/*}
    { [ -z "$bin" ] || [ -z "$bindir" ]; } && return

    cd -- "$bindir"
}
```

Comment: Great answer! Never knew that `which` is that evil! :)

Comment: @hek2mgl `evil` is a strong word but it isn't the go-to tool many people think it is.