# How to change pwd directory in Shell file?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have this shell file which is supposed to extract data from a different directory, but it tries to extract files from current directory with "$pwd". How can I specify a folder to extract these files from, such that it comes from /home/gnssb/Desktop/Data instead of /home/gnssb/Desktop/Data/shell_scripts

```
    #!/bin/sh

    ORIG_DIR=$(pwd)
    basedir="../"

    year=2016;
    init_month=01;
    end_month=01;
    init_date=01;
    end_date=26;

    casesinp="${ORIG_DIR}/./cases-inp"
```

Comment: Replace `$(pwd)` with `"$PWD/.."`?

Comment: where (what path) your script resides?

Comment: Nothing in this script extracts anything at all. Please ensure that what you're showing us follows the [mcve] definition -- it should be the shortest possible code *that actually reproduces a specific problem described in the question when run*. A program that just assigns a bunch of variables is not a program that extracts files into the wrong directory.

Comment: That said, you might find [Bash variable substitution vs basename and dirname](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22401091/bash-variable-substitution-vs-dirname-and-basename) interesting, insofar as this question might be asking for the functionality that `dirname` provides.

Answer (score 0):

try adding a `cd`?

```
#!/bin/sh

ORIG_DIR=$(pwd)
basedir="../"

year=2016;
init_month=01;
end_month=01;
init_date=01;
end_date=26;

casesinp="${ORIG_DIR}/./cases-inp"

cd ${ORIG_DIR}/..
NEWPWD=$(pwd)

# NEWPWD would be level above shell-scripts now

# now, whatever commands following that gave you the wrong data before
# but on NEWPWD
```

Comment: You don't need `$(pwd)`. There's a special variable `$PWD`.